# File from node4excel to multer

Tags: javascript, typescript, multer

I create an funciton to generating an xlsx file with node4excel library. This function work fine and generate me new files. But I want to save in database a link to this files. I try using multer from `express-multer` but it does not work and do not save me files in multer destination.

my code:

```
//multer function
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('files', multerOptions))
uploadFile(@UploadedFile() file){
    console.log(file);
}
```

```
//generating new file with excel4node
workBook.write('files.xlsx')
```

```
//trying to save this file with using multer
this.uploadFile(workBook.write('raport.xls'));
```

but it not work :/

can someone tell me how to create an link to new files which can be stored in `./files` folder?

Answer (score 0):

To save excel file you need to follow points below

- just use `node4excel` to create the file
- then save this file with `workBook.write('xxxx.xlsx')`. but you need to change `xxxx.xlsx` to `` workBook.write(`${uuid_v4}.xlsx`) ``. why we use `uuid_v4` as file name ? to overcame overridning old file when save new file with same name
- now we have excel file with unique name saved in specific path in own server. let's say full path for this file is `/app/data/files/5fe3cc43-e1c3-4c1d-a907-b1636b57a892.xlsx`. remember to save file in this path you need to use `` workBook.write(`/app/data/files/${uuid_v4}.xlsx`) ``.
- now we missing some thing how to download it ? simply we save file name in database like `fileName: "5fe3cc43-e1c3-4c1d-a907-b1636b57a892.xlsx"`. after save it we use the same `uuid_v4` to save file name in database.
- now we need to create endpoint exposed to user. when request to it with file name we will check if this user have permission to download this file if ok we will send this file to him. so we need user to send the `filename` to know what file he need, `token` to check permission (identify this user).

so you didn't need to use `multer`. `multer` help you to upload file not create file then sent it to client.

> NOTE: All points above around Node.js (backend).

Comment: actually you will store file in file system in `DATA` path then save file name to database. in other side when client need to download the file we assume the client have the file name then send it to the server then server will get this file from the `DATA` path then the server will sent it to client using `res.download()`. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: when I say `DATA` path I mean path like it `/app/data/files`.